# How to configure Spring io for reading from file and process string as message and push to queue

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-io

Steps I need:

1. read file
2. take xml string from file as text
3. push the text as message to QUeue

How to do configure this in Spring io? File inbound channel, outbound channel queue, how to add processor?

Answer (score 1):

Check this sample code

```
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/file
```

In the below configuration

```
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/file/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/fileCopyDemo-file.xml
```

instead of `<file:outbound-channel-adapter` you can have outbound adapter of your choice

Comment: Also see the [JMS Chapter in the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html).